# Magento2: How to bulk update attribute: weight

Tags: magento2

I will try update in bulk for all products attribute: `weight`

But When I select all products and then click on update attributes I dont see `weight` field.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Export the csv file. And export csv file only two field like `sku field` and `weight field` and save two files csv.Again import the modified csv file import.

And second Using `SQL`

```
select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code='weight'; it will give you id of that attribute

select * from catalog_product_entity_decimal where attribute_id=82 // find that attribute value

update catalog_product_entity_decimal set value='' where attribute_id=82 and value='0.3'
```

Hope this help you

Thanks ...